# '$(' is not allowed as a global variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew

I wrote this line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

at my command line and it's not working.

I have the message:

```
-e:1: '$(' is not allowed as a global variable name.
```

Here's the screen capture of the error:

[image]

Comment: double quotes, maybe?

Comment: I tried with simple quotes and it's not working either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That script is designed to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which is a **Mac OS X** package manager. According to your screenshot, you are running on Windows.

The reason of the error it's likely to be caused by the fact that the shell on Windows is different than the shell on Unix systems (specifically in this case Max OS X), therefore some commands may be different.

Apart from the error itself, whatever you are trying to do doesn't make sense at all. Homebrew is not designed to be installed on Windows.